# Array notation in angular forEach

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I've just spent an hour debugging a very trivial problem. But I don't understand why this behaviour occurs sometimes and under what conditions. To illustrate my issue let's break out an example.

```
$scope.vm.PetList = pets; // pets comes from resolved request
$scope.vm.Person = person; // person comes from resolved request

// init logic
if (angular.isDefined($scope.vm.Person.Pets) && $scope.vm.Person.Pets.length) {
    angular.forEach($scope.vm.Person.Pets, function (pet) {
        // this is the part that works sometimes
        pet = FunctionThatReturnsObjectOrNull($scope.vm.PetList, 'Id', pet.Id);
    });

    angular.forEach($scope.vm.Person.Pets, function (pet, pkey) {
        // this works every time
        $scope.vm.Person.Pets[pkey] = FunctionThatReturnsObjectOrNull($scope.vm.PetList, 'Id', pet.Id);
    });
}
```

I don't know why I'd want to look up a person's pets from a pets collection in this particular example but it should suffice an illustration where I encounter a problem.

It is important to note that the right side of the assignment always evaluates correctly. It's the assignment to `pet` variable in the first example that does not always represent the change in the array.

I understand why `$scope.vm.Person.Pets[pkey]` work every time because that is the correct array notation. But the `pet =` notation can save the hassle to tracking `keys` for nested arrays.

```
angular.forEach(collection, function (a) {
    if (a.collection.length > 0) {
        angular.forEach(a.collection, function (b) {
            b = doSomething();
        });
    }
});
```

If anyone can shed some light on this I would appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pet` supplied to your iterator function by `angular.forEach` is a 'reference' to the object within the array. Calling `pet = ...` is reassigning that reference to point to a new object, not changing the original object.
`pets[pkey] = ...` is updating the reference in the array.

Comment: I get what you saying because I can add/edit/remove properties on ``pet`` reference all day long and it works fine. But I don't get why it works sometimes because as you said reassigning ``pet`` reference to a new object does not change the original object.

Comment: Do you see that behaviour in your 'pets' example or is there maybe some additional complexity that's not shown here? Or some relationship between `PetList` and `Person.Pets` that's not shown here?

Comment: Usually, in my init logic I would set additional properties on ``PetList`` for each object. Subsequently, I would update ``Person.Pets`` and I normally use the shorthand ``pet = ...`` notation in a ``forEach`` loop. It works most of the time. But that may be the case if my resolver ``FunctionThatReturnsObjectOrNull()`` returns objects with ``$$hashKey`` property which angular is able to resolve and update each pet by reference? Most of the time I am fine if ``Person.Pets`` reference objects in ``PetList``. Not sure it is related though. What do you think?